# Calculate Residual Norm for Multiple Regression in Python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

Given a matrix X of predictors, Y vector of observations, and theta model parameters, how can the residual norm be calculated using Python, numPy, or sciPy?

Comment: Hey @Jackson! What have you tried so far? :-)

Comment: I've fumbled through numpy.linalg.lstsq, linalg.norm and a few attempts at manually calculations to solve the following equation:  ∥r∥2=∥Xθ∗−y∥2
  but with no luck.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add the equation and any other valuable information to your original post? I took the liberty to add the `python` and `numpy` tags, but I thought I'd give you the honor of doing the rest (since I don't know anything about the topic at hand). 

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you want to compute the residual 2-norm for a linear model, this is a very straightforward operation in `numpy`. Here is a simple example for  `n=10` observations with `d=3` parameters and all random matrix values:

```
import numpy as np 
n = 10
d = 3
X = np.random.rand(n, d) 
theta = np.random.rand(d, 1)
y = np.random.rand(n, 1)
r = np.linalg.norm(X.dot(theta) - y)
```

The `dot` method computes standard matrix multiplication in `numpy`. The default norm used by `numpy.linalg.norm` is the 2-norm.

Comment: Many thanks.  That solved the problem.  Given the formula ∥r∥2=∥Xθ∗−y∥2, how would you know that Xθ∗ required the transpose method?

Comment: @Jackson Happy to help! I'm not exactly sure what that formula means or where it's from - is the star symbol after theta a conjugate transpose? Could you link me to a website explaining it? Also, I didn't use the transpose operator (`.T` in `numpy`), but in general you have to check that the matrices you are multiplying have the correct number of rows and columns.